# Can I use userTimeline() in R to get one's tweets from a certain time interval?

Tags: r

If I'd like to get all the tweets from, say, @elonmusk, from Jan 1, 2016 to Apr 1, 2016, is there a way to do it with userTimeline() or other R functions?

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: No. The R functions can only provide data made available by the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public). All tweets for all time periods are not made publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on MrFlick's answer. I believe with the API you can:

1. When using searchTwitter(), get tweets from up to 6-9 days previously: `searchTwitter("elon+musk")`
2. Get up to 3200 tweets at a time from a user's timeline with userTimeline(): `userTimeline("elonmusk", n = 3200)`
3. You can also specify the maxID parameter in userTimeline(). If someone has more than 3200 tweets (find out quickly with: `emusk <- getUser("elonmusk")` and then `em$statusesCount`) and pass a tweet id to get tweets before then.

Then filter on the results. But sadly not a direct way of getting Jan 1, 2016 to Apr 1, 2016 as per the API yet.